# A formula for the exterior angles of an irregular polygon, given interior angles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

So I took a challenge from my Geometry teacher to create code that when the user gives the computer how many angles / sides a polygon has and the angle of each of the interior angles it could find each of the exterior angles whether it is **regular or irregular**. For example the user tells the computer they have a four-sided shape (quadrilateral), the interior angles are $70, 75, 110, 145$. The computer would then be able to output each corresponding angle in the proper order. My problem is that with coding you can't just type in the human logic so I need a formula to work from: what on earth would be a formula that could apply to any polygon with any number of sides (**irregular or regular**)?

Answer (score 1):

At each vertex of the polygon, the interior angle and exterior angle must sum to $180$. You can use this to find the value of each exterior angle.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is not complete, because you can have a non convex polygon (i.e one interior angle can be 240) and to say that $180-$`input_angle` is not all correct.

Thr proper way to to this is:

1. read angles and save them as a list `angles_list`
2. initialize and empty array with size equal to `angles_list` with name `exteriors`.
3. loop over elements in `angles_list`, if `element` is greater than 180, then append to `exteriors` $360-$`element`, else append $180-$`element`
4. return `exteriors`

Also you can add validations to check if the input angles indeed correspond to a polygon (i.e, the sum of angles must be a multiple of 180)